# Xposed access to variable in Function

Tags: java, android, local-variables, xposed, xposed-framework

Iam working on a XPosedModule but I need help:

I have hooked a method, which has some local variables (only accessable in this method), but I need to access these variable. I tried

`XposedHelpers.getObjectField(param.thisObject,"OBJECT_I_NEED");`

But my experience with this function is that it returns Global variables only but I need the variable which is only in a function and not accessable in whole class.

Thanks alot;

- Jojii

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't replace a local variable inside a method. This is a limitation of Xposed API.
Instead, you can hook the method to do something before or after it's called or to completely replace it.